# Genus of the graph $K_{m,2,2,2}$

Tags: graph-theory

What is the genus of this complete $4-$partite graph, $K_{m,2,2,2}$, where $m \in \mathbb{N}$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps try http://math.stackexchange.com :-) Good luck

Comment: @DavidRoberts There is a similar questions in math.stackexchange.com, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/503277/genus-of-complete-4-partite-graph, but it has no answer. By the way, thank you for the advice.

Comment: Is this trivial?  I don't think so.

Comment: I think it not easy. There are also many papers to find the genus of this kind of graph. For example this one http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0095895675900830

Comment: I retract my dismissive advice.

Comment: One lower bound is the genus of $K_{m,4,2}$ which is $m-2$, according to http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0195669804000617