# Genus of the graph $K_{4,2,2,2}$

Tags: graph-theory, sage

I have ask this question in math.stackexchange, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/683217/genus-of-the-graph-k-4-2-2-2). Since, there is no answer and apart from that i feel that the problem is difficult, i would like to ask it here. The problem is to find the genus of $K_{4,2,2,2}$. I want a theoretical technique(if possible), otherwise using sage programming is good enough. I have tried using sage for a week now, but my computer is too slow. Thanks for any help.

The graph $K_{4,2,2,2}$ is a complete $4-$partite graph, that is, its vertex set can be partition into 4 disjoint parts of size 4, 2, 2 and 2, and any two vertices are adjacent if and only if they belong to different parts.

Comment: You could, perhaps, add a brief definition of this graph.

Comment: I have added...

Comment: See question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/157894/genus-of-the-graph-k-m-2-2-2

Comment: @F.C. But that question has no answer. If that question has an answer, then it will be an answer to this question also.

Comment: One lower bound is the genus of $K_{4,4,2}$, which is $2$. An upper bound is the genus of $K_{10}$, which is $4$.

Comment: Since the answer is between $2$ and $4$, as shown by @DouglasZare, you might want to try the algebraic approach of Diestel and Bruhn (http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0095895608000476). In fact, you might want to contact Henning Bruhn who might be able to compute this for you using their characterization!

Comment: Here is a paper that seems relevant (based on the title):     Said Bettayeb, Quan T. Nguyen, "The genus of the complete multipartite graph and the complete multi-layered graph," aiccsa, pp.1-4, ACS/IEEE International Conference on Computer Systems and Applications - AICCSA 2010, 2010. http://doi.ieeecomputersociety.org/10.1109/AICCSA.2010.5587024

Comment: If I'm not misreading, Theorem 4.1 from the reference given by David Wood states that the genus of the complete k-partite graph with partitions of sizes $V_1,V_2,\dots,V_k$ is $\sum_{i<j}\left\lceil\frac{(V_i-2)(V_j-2)}{4}\right\rceil+\left\lceil\frac{(k-3)(k-4)}{12}\right\rceil$, which gives zero for your graph. It also gives 1 for $K_{4,4,2}$ so I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: @j.c. That a serious problem. Actually I don't have any access to this paper. Can you Figure what is the problem?

Comment: @bor I find their proof of Theorem 4.1 very unclear.  Here is a copy of their paper https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8101832/bettayebnguyen.pdf . And by the way, the paper cited by Felix Goldberg has a longer preprint version here http://preprint.math.uni-hamburg.de/public/papers/hbm/hbm2006251.pdf , the published article in particular refers to this version for more background

Comment: Thank you so much @j.c. . I will also try to understand the paper..

Comment: @j.c. I think the proof of Theorem 4.1 is not correct and the result is not correct.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I understand it's been years since this question was asked, but I figured I should give an answer for anyone still interested.

From the Euler equation, if $K_{4,2,2,2}$ has genus 2, it would actually triangulate $S_2$. Searching for triangular embeddings is much quicker than enumerating over all embeddings (as sage does). In fact, [Jungerman](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82616223.pdf) was able to find a triangular embedding of $K_{18}-K_3$ in about half an hour back in the 1970s. Applying such an algorithm on $K_{4,2,2,2}$ shows that it has no such embedding on $S_2$.

Not only is $K_{4,2,2,2}$ a subgraph of $K_{10}$, as observed by @Douglas Zare, but it is a subgraph of $K_{10}-K_3$ as well, which has genus 3 (see [Youngs, "The Heawood Map-Coloring Problem--Cases 1, 7, 10"](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82726666.pdf)).

These two parts together show that the genus of $K_{4,2,2,2}$ is 3.